# Crear multiples archivo de rutas en Vuejs

Tags: vue.js, router

Tengo varios archivos de rutas:

> Main.js

```
Vue.use(Router)
const routes = [
    Auth
]

const router = new Router({
  routes
})
```

Estoy importando las rutas de mi archivo Auth.js que es el siguiente

> auth.js

```
import Login              from '@/components/auth/Login'
import Recovery           from '@/components/auth/Recovery'
import WelcomeActive           from '@/components/auth/WelcomeActive'

const routes = Object.assign(
        {
            path: '/login',
            component: Login
        },
        {
            path: '/recovery',
            component: Recovery,
            meta: {
                protectedLogin: true //Proteger ruta en caso de que este autentificado.
            }
        },
        {
            path: '/activate/success',
            component: WelcomeActive
        },
)

console.log('routes', routes)
export default routes
```

el problema es que la consola me arroja el ultimo *objeto* utilizando la funcion `assign` intente solo colocar `Object(...)` y me arroba solo el *login*. Esto quiere decir que no esta retornando todo mi objecto de **routes**
¿Cómo debería ser?

Answer (score 1):

En tu `index.js` estás importando `HomeRoutes` dentro del array `routes` que está siendo exportado como un `array` desde `home.js` entonces `routes` es un `array` de otro `array` cuando debería ser un `array` de `objetos`.

Tendrías que exportar como objeto el contenido que tienes en `home.js`, para luego importarlo como lo estás haciendo en tu `index.js`.

**update**: 
deberías exportar:

```
export default {
  path: '/empleos',
  name: 'JobsList',
  component: JobsList,
}
```

Comment: Esto es correcto, sin embargo no es una ruta, son varias.

Comment: entonces hazlo como spread operator: `routes: [...HomeRoutes]`

Comment: He modificado mi pregunta, puedes echarle un vistazo?